# Odoo - Remove Boilerplate Import From Outer Folder

Tags: python, import, module, odoo

I have Odoo project structure like this image below

[image]

[image]

I don't want to change any code from the `odoo14` folder because it's the source code from Odoo repository. All code I write will put on `custom` folder. When I want to import `odoo` from `my_model` python file, I have to write `odoo` word twice like this code

```
from odoo14.odoo import api, fields, models
```

I want to remove the `odoo14` so when I need to import from Odoo I just need to write like this

```
from odoo import api, fields, models
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by installing the Odoo package as a local library using pip.

```
pip install C:\My\Odoo\Directory
```